# How to access Firebase Firestore from GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access a Firebase Firestore DB from a GCP Cloud Function - the function is not part of the Firebase project - so two separate projects.  When I config/init the DB I get a permissions error

def hello_world(request):

```
import firebase_admin
import flask
import json
from flask import request
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore    


try: 
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={           
        'apiKey': '<appkey>',
        'authDomain': '<authdomain>',
        'databaseURL': '<url>',
        'projectId': '<projID>',
        'storageBucket': '<bucket>',
        'messagingSenderId': '<id>',
        'appId': '<app ID>'
    })
except:
    print("DB already init")


#end db init
db = firestore.client()
# end db setup
```

I expect/want the result to be to initialize the DB so I can read/write to it, but I get an error:

Error: function crashed. Details:
403 Missing or insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the app init settings for web, you need to use the sdk key instead. Go to Settings -> Services Account -> and generate your key.

[image]

Include the json file instead of those parameters. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you!  I'm confused on how to include a package.json file in GCP?  do you store it on cloud storage or is there a way to embed it directly in the function?

Comment: there are several ways to do this, if this is for getting started, I would recommend to include it as part of your project (upload it together), if this is more like production level stuff, you will need some kind of secret management or yes storage it on cloud storage and load it dynamically, whatever works best for ur use case :)!

Comment: ok - additional q:  I have modified the code to put the json file on storage and am getting it into 'blob': 
 cred = credentials(blob.download_as_string())
 firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

still yields an error.  I'm not sure the syntax on the initialize_app()?

Comment: I never used before that way, local would be something like cred = credentials.Certificate('/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

Comment: Take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin